# How can I change my permissions in phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, magento, permissions, phpmyadmin

I am trying to set up magento on my localhost, and had to create a database for it via phpmyadmin.  anyways, one of the setup steps was to enter in a user name and password, but it wouldn't let you leave the password blank so I went and changed it.  now, I can't access anything... not MAMP, phpMyAdmin, any local sites, etc.  I can't seem to change permissions via the command line.

I am the only user on my computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

phpMyAdmin has a config file located within the same directory, called **config.inc.php** . Change your password there ( given that you use "config" mode to memorize password )

Comment: haha woah that came off stupid... what i meant was, what do i edit in the file? I don't see my password anywhere

Comment: It should be in `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']` if it is really stored in the `config.inc.php`. Also remember to flush the permissions (by restarting or `flush privileges`) otherwise MySQL still uses the old Password.

Answer (score 1):

Open command line.

`sudo mysql`

then `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'new_user'@'localhost';`  where `new_user` is your username

Then `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`and you're good to go

PS: `exit` to leave mysql